# How to reorganize 2 columns of data with duplicates in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Sorry if the title is confusing. I have been up almost all night trying to solve this problem and I'm not sure how to word it. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a spreadsheet with Names in Column A and ID Numbers in Column B. It looks like this

```
Sally     1004
Sally     1005
Sally     1006
Robert    1007
Robert    1008
```

ect.

I have another spreadsheet which due to some circumstances, I cannot legally filter in any way that has the names like this

```
Sally
Sally
Robert
Robert
Robert
```

They are all alphabetical but as you can see in Sally's case she shows up more times in the first instance then in the second sheet which is completely fine. However, Robert shows up more times in the second sheet then in the first and I need this to return some sort of error. I also need Sheet2 to have to ID numbers in order that they appear.This is the end goal

```
Sally     1004
Sally     1005
Robert    1007
Robert    1008
Robert    #N/A           (or any other error)
```

I've spend hours trying to find an array formula to work and have had no success. If you have any idea how I should proceed I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

`=INDEX(Table1[ID],SMALL(IF(A2=Table1[name],ROW(Table1[name])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[name]]),10^9),COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:A2,A2)))`

Of course this is also an array formula.

- `IF(A2=Table1[name],ROW(Table1[name])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[name]]),10^9)`

  - returns row number for rows in the source table containing the actual name
    (corrected by row number of table heading, in order to work correctly in index function)
  - returns `10^9`for others (just to get a big number not confusing `SMALL` function, maybe `""` would work too)
- `COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:A2,A2)` - count number of names above current row
- `SMALL(IF(...),10^9),COUNTIF(...))` - returns next smallest (corrected) row number
- `=INDEX(Table1[ID],SMALL(...))` - returns ID

For better readability of the formula I've converted your first range to a table, of course you can use addresses too.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain this please?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This is quite literally a night saver. Thank you